# Construct a tree object for Azure blob container

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, asp.net-core-2.1

I would like to read all files and folders on blob storage and display it on my application (ASP.NET CORE 2.1) in hierarchy model.

Here is my Action Method

```
public async Task<ActionResult> List()
        {
            CloudBlobContainer container = GetCloudBlobContainer();
            //List<string> blobs = new List<string>();
            BlobResultSegment resultSegment = container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null).Result;
            var tree = new List<TreeNode>();
            int i = 1;
            foreach (IListBlobItem item in resultSegment.Results)
            {
                if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
                {
                    CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob) item;
                    //blobs.Add(blob.Name);
                }
                else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudPageBlob))
                {
                    CloudPageBlob blob = (CloudPageBlob) item;
                    //blobs.Add(blob.Name);
                }
                else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlobDirectory))
                {
                    CloudBlobDirectory dir = (CloudBlobDirectory) item;
                    var response = await dir.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(true, BlobListingDetails.None, int.MaxValue, null,
                        null, null);
                    tree.Add(new TreeNode
                    {
                        Id = i,
                        Key = dir.Prefix,
                        Name = dir.Prefix.TrimEnd('/'),
                        Url = dir.Uri.ToString(),
                        //HasChildren = response.Results.Any(),
                        //Children = response.Results.Select(x => new TreeNode
                        //{
                        //    Key = x.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString(),
                        //    Name = x.StorageUri.SecondaryUri.ToString(),
                        //    Url = x.Uri.ToString(),
                        //    HasChildren = false
                        //}).ToList()
                    });
                    foreach (var blobItem in response.Results)
                    {
                        tree.Add(GetNode(blobItem, i));
                    }

                    //blobs.Add(dir.Uri.ToString());
                    i++;
                }
            }
            return View(tree);
        }
```

TreeNode Class:

```
public class TreeNode
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public bool HasChildren { get; set; }
        public virtual List<TreeNode> Children { get; set; }
        public string ParentKey { get; set; }
    }
```

How do I recursively read the blob item details and construct the tree

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What excitably is your current problem/question? Looks like what your asking a for a link to something like https://www.syncfusion.com/aspnet-core-ui-controls/treeview

Comment: @Leonardo How do I recursively read the blob item details and construct the tree

Comment: @HaBo there is no tree. There are no folders. Whether AWS S3 or Azure Blobs, a container contains a *flat* list of files whose names look like paths. `aaa/bbb/ccc/x.txt` doesn't mean there are any folders. You can specify in code that `/` is a path separator. When you ask for the "contents" of `aaa/bbb` the cloud provider performs a simple prefix search and returns everyting that *stats* with the "folder path".

Comment: @HaBo the reason for this is that a folder structure simply doesn't scale for a cloud container that can contain many millions of files. BTW I'd suggest you clean up the code too. Instead of using reflection to get the type, just use `someting is someType` if you really need it. In ASP.NET Core of course you can use pattern matching eg `switch (item) { case CloudBlob blob: blobs.Add(blob.Name); break; case CloudBlobDirectory dir : ...}`

Comment: @Habo other serious errors - using `.Result`. `List` is an asynchronous method already. Use `var resultSegment = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null);` instead of `.Result`. Using `ListBlobsSegmentedAsync` itself is a problem - this method is meant to load one batch of results at a time inside a loop. The question's code though calls it just once, loading only one batch of results. If you wanted to retrieve all items, you could have used `ListBlobs` instead.

Comment: There is no ListBlobs method

Answer (score 1):

This is how I ended up doing it

Action Method

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> List()
        {
            CloudBlobContainer container = GetCloudBlobContainer();
            List<string> blobs = new List<string>();
            BlobResultSegment resultSegment = container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null).Result;
            var tree = new List<TreeNode>();
            int i = 1;
            foreach (IListBlobItem item in resultSegment.Results)
            {
                if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
                {
                    CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob) item;
                    blobs.Add(blob.Name);
                }
                else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudPageBlob))
                {
                    CloudPageBlob blob = (CloudPageBlob) item;
                    blobs.Add(blob.Name);
                }
                else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlobDirectory))
                {
                    CloudBlobDirectory dir = (CloudBlobDirectory) item;
                    tree.Add(new TreeNode
                    {
                        Id = i,
                        Type = TreeNodeType.Folder,
                        Key = dir.Prefix,
                        Name = dir.Prefix.TrimEnd('/'),
                        Url = dir.Uri.ToString()
                    });
                    i++;
                }
            }

            foreach (var treeNode in tree)
            {
                if (treeNode.Type == TreeNodeType.Folder)
                    treeNode.Children = await GetBlobDirectoriesAsync(container, treeNode);
            }
            return View(tree);
        }
```

Recursive Tree Nodes

```
private async Task<List<TreeNode>> GetBlobDirectoriesAsync(CloudBlobContainer container, TreeNode parentNode)
        {
            var directory = container.GetDirectoryReference(parentNode.Key);
            var folders = await directory.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null);
            var tree = new List<TreeNode>();
            if (folders.Results.Any())
                parentNode.HasChildren = true;
            foreach (var folder in folders.Results.ToList())
            {
                if (folder is CloudBlobDirectory directoryItem)
                {
                    tree.Add(new TreeNode
                    {
                        Id = 0,
                        Type = TreeNodeType.Folder,
                        Key = directoryItem.Prefix,
                        Name = directoryItem.Prefix.Replace(directoryItem.Parent.Prefix, "").TrimEnd('/'),
                        Url = directoryItem.Uri.ToString()
                    });
                }
                if (folder is CloudPageBlob pageItem)
                {
                    tree.Add(new TreeNode
                    {
                        Id = 0,
                        Key = pageItem.Name,
                        Name = pageItem.Name,
                        Url = pageItem.Uri.ToString()
                    });
                }
                if (folder is CloudBlockBlob blockItem)
                {
                    tree.Add(new TreeNode
                    {
                        Id = 0,
                        Type = TreeNodeType.File,
                        Key = blockItem.Name.Replace(blockItem.Parent.Prefix,""),
                        Name = blockItem.Name.Replace(blockItem.Parent.Prefix, ""),
                        Url = blockItem.Uri.ToString()
                    });
                }
            }

            foreach (var treeNode in tree)
            {
                if(treeNode.Type == TreeNodeType.Folder)
                    treeNode.Children = await GetBlobDirectoriesAsync(container, treeNode);
            }
            return tree;
        }
```

Comment: Your solution works great!! but it is taking too much time to fetch all blobs and subdirectories inside parent directories, is there any way to optimize code???